# What is the use of TLS concept in the first network of fabric samples of hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

How can we implement  TLS in first-network?i have tried by adding the below section in peers.What is the need to configure peers by Tls?

```
CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
```

I am working on multi organisation network setup using first network of fabric samples.one of the organisation say org1 has created a channel by passing tls certs of orderer ,the other organisation org2 has to fetch the channel created by org1 and join the peers into the channel.when i do fetch action using peer channel fetch by passing tls certs of orderer ,i got the error like

```
  peer channel fetch config-o orderer.example.com:7050 -c channelone1 -f --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem 
connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 98.124.199.121:7050: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...
```

and in orderer logs ,i got error as :

```
TLS handshake failed with error tls: client didn't provide a certificate {"server": "Orderer", "remote address": "172.24.0.4:49608"}
```

Created the channel using:

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c channelone1 -f ./channel-artifacts/channel-one.tx --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

Output is: Received block is 0

Answer (score 2):

By default the first-network will start with TLS enabled.

The four environment variables you refer to are included in the file `base/peer-base.yaml` the the peer-base file is "included" by use of the `extends:` and `file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml`

Comment: @R Thatcher .. Thanks for your reply.I faced an issue when i try to fetch a channel created .I found the error in docker logs of orderer like "TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certifica te {"server": "Orderer", "remote address": "192.168.0.77:34362"}".@R Thatcher

Comment: That error in the orderer log says that the command (or function) that you are using is using the wrong cafile - my guess is that you are tying to use a peer's ca file when you are connecting to the orderer.

Comment: I have provided the ca file path of orderer.Still i am facing the same issue.Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Please update your question with the exact command/code/task you are trying, including whether you are running from inside another container (peer/cli?) and include in the question the errors on the terminal and the orderer.